# Different Services injected onto same screen

Tags: dependency-injection, aurelia

I have two screens:

1. Screen1(Empleado-empleado-form.js, empleado-form.js is called from empleado.js) where Service1 is injected.
2. Screen2(Departamento-departamento.js) where Service 2 is injected

This is a repro of my error:

1. When navigating to Screen1 the Service1 is injected.
2. When navigating to Screen2 Service2 is injected.
3. When navigating back to Screen1, Service2 is injected.

I suppose that the intented behavior is that each Service is injected into the  screen with @injected not to randomly inject to the next Screen.

This is the github's project: https://github.com/DiegoGallegos4/aurelia-test;

- Screen 1 is located: src/departamento(services is inside)
- Screen 2 is located: src/empleado(service is inside, empleado-form.js is where empleado-service.js is injected.)

I use the following pattern:

```
@inject(Screen1Service)
export class Screen1{
    constructor(service){
        this.service = service
    }

    ...service use to fetch/post data
}
```

If a repro is needed, let me know I can make a gist using promises. However, I dont know is navigation would be available on gist.

Comment: How do you know "When navigating back to Screen1, Service2 is injected"?

Comment: That's why I infer. On both screens, there is a custom-table component and when you navigate back to Screen 1. The data fetched from Service2 in seen in the custom-table component.

Comment: I believe the injection was not wrong. Problem lies in the way you config `HttpClient`. To confirm it, can you `console.log(this.service)` in screen1's `activate()`?

Comment: The service is injected correctly. What changes on navigation is the url. Somehow the url of Service2 is used on Service 1 when navigating back. Why is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service injection was indeed correct. The problem lies in the way these services use `HttpClient`.

Each service class configure `HttpClient` in its constructor. Since a single `HttpClient` in injected into all services, the latter created service override previous configuration. Moreover, each service is a singleton itself, so its constructor and thus `HttpClient` configuration only run once.

Therefore, the navigation order matters. When navigate from Screen1 -> Screen2 -> back to Screen1 , the last configuration in Service2 has effect. If you change the sequence to Screen2 -> Screen1 -> Screen2, you will observe the opposite.

To fix this issue, you should configure `HttpClient` only at one place, e.g in `main` or `app`. See this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999448/aurelia-configure-fetch-client)

Comment: How would you configure the api url for each specific url or you would put in each fetch?

Comment: I would configure the API base URL (well, the config method name is `withBaseUrl` for a purpose), and use relative URL in each fetch. E.g in your case, base URL can be `http://hrm.dev/api`

Comment: or use aurelia-api. it lets you define endpoints in a nicely fashion:
http://aurelia-api.spoonx.org/configuration.html